# Powershell: Can't close application when certain condition is met

Tags: windows, powershell

I've had trouble closing my powershell script. I've got some forms from PowerGUI and included a function at the beginning of the handler that loads the form.

Simple task: Check a variable. If it's $false, close the program/application.

exit and break throw a Microsoft .Net Error, which can be clicked away when pressing "Continue" and the script  continues.

Here are the details of the .net error. http://pastebin.com/phdspwsT

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about posting the script that causes the error too?

Comment: If ($check_auth) {}
 Else {
  Break
 }

Comment: So if you create a .ps1 script file that contains *just* the code above, you'll get the the error as per Pastebin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to close the form during the `OnLoad` event don't use break.  Try calling `$sender.Close()`.  Another thing to try is `$sender.DialogResult = 'Cancel'`.